# Understanding tuple syntax in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, subquery

I've always used the `IN (val1, val2, ...)` syntax quite easily when testing for a bunch of values. However, I'm wondering what type of data structure it actually evaluates to, is this a table function? For example:

```
-- to populate data
CREATE TABLE main_territory (
  name varchar NOT NULL,
  is_fake_territory integer NOT NULL,
  code varchar NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO main_territory (name, is_fake_territory, code) VALUES ('Afghanistan', 0, 'AF'), ('Albania', 0, 'AL'), ('Algeria', 0, 'DZ');
```

```
select '1' as "query#", * from main_territory where code in ('AF', 'AL') union all
select '2' as "query#", * from main_territory where code in (select 'AF' UNION ALL select 'AL') UNION ALL
select '3' as "query#", * from main_territory where code in (select code from main_territory where name ='Albania' or name = 'Afghanistan')
```

[image]

The second and third queries return a one-columned table (is this called a scalar-table?), and so I would imagine doing `(expr1, expr2, ...)` does the same thing -- it evaluates to a one-columed table. Is that accurate, or what actual data type is this?

Comment: What dbms did you use? `mysql <> postgresql` thanks

Comment: @D-Shih I tried it on both. The above insert though is from postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not call the `IN ( )` predicate tuple comparison. An example of tuple comparison (aka row constructor comparison) is:

```
WHERE (col1, col2) = ('abc', 123)
```

Or you can even do multivalued row constructor comparison:

```
WHERE (col1, col2) IN (('abc', 123), ('xyz', 456))
```

The examples you show are simply the `IN ( )` predicate, which compares a single value to a list of values. If the value matches any of those in the list, the predicate is satisfied. The list can either be a fixed list of expressions or literals:

```
WHERE code IN ('AF', 'AL')
```

Or it can be the result of a subquery:

```
WHERE code IN (SELECT code FROM ...)
```

How this is implemented depends on the code of the respective RDBMS. It might have to materialize the result of the subquery and store it as a list internally. In some software, they may use a temporary table with one column as the data structure to store the result of the subquery. Then the `IN ( )` predicate can be executed as a join against that temporary table. If there's one thing an SQL engine ought to be able to do efficiently, it's a join. :-)

But this might be expensive if the result of the subquery is millions of rows. In that case, a clever optimizer would "factor out" the `IN ( )` predicate and just do a join. That is, it would read each value of `code` and do an index lookup into the second table's `code` column. This means there's no data structure per se, it's just the evaluation of a join.

The real answer would be implementation-dependent. Both MySQL and PostgreSQL are open-source, so you can try downloading and reading the code yourself if you want to know the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion is understandable, since these are actually two different kinds of `IN`:

```
WHERE expr IN (2, 3, 4, ...)
WHERE expr IN (SELECT ...)
```

The first will be converted to an array like this:

```
                    QUERY PLAN                  
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Seq Scan on tab
   Filter: (expr = ANY ('{2,3,4,...}'::integer[]))
```

or, if the list has only one element, to

```
      QUERY PLAN     
══════════════════════
 Seq Scan on tab
   Filter: (expr = 2)
```

The second will be executed as a join, for example:

```
            QUERY PLAN             
═══════════════════════════════════
 Hash Join
   Hash Cond: (tab.expr = sub.col)
   ->  Seq Scan on tab
   ->  Hash
         ->  Seq Scan on sub
```

So, to answer your question: A plain `IN` list will be converted to an array, and `IN` becomes `= ANY`.